# How to obtain the object type of another object's property in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Let's suppose we have the following two classes' definitions:

```cs
public class ParentClass
{
   public ChildClass[] Children{ get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }
}
```

We can iterate through the properties of `ParentClass` using `System.Type` but I could not find a way in dotnet core to determine the non-array type of `Children` which is `ChildClass`. For example, I'd like to have a test like the following one always to pass:

```cs
Type childType = GetChildTypeOf(typeof(ParentClass));
Assert.True(childType == typeof(ChildClass));
```

In that case, how should `GetChildTypeOf(...)` be implemented?

Comment: What have you already tried? Please edit your question with the code you are currently using and having trouble with.

Comment: I am looking for a generic way to be able to achieve this goal. Those two classes were just an example to express my idea.

Comment: What if the class has more than one property? Which one would you consider as "child" then?

Comment: Have you tried to implement `GetChildTypeOf` yet? You mention you have code iterating over the properties of `ParentClass`, but could you show that in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering there could be more than one property, the `GetChildTypeOf` better return `List<Type>` objects.

```cs
private static List<Type> GetChildTypeOf(Type parent)
{
    var res = new List<Type>();

    var props = parent.GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        var propType = prop.PropertyType;
        var elementType = propType.GetElementType();
        res.Add(elementType);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Then you make your assertion:

```cs
var childType = GetChildTypeOf(typeof(ParentClass));
Assert.True(childType.First() == typeof(ChildClass));
```

Probably it would be even better to have one method to return them all, and one to return a child type element by given property name.

Edit: Here is how it should look for a specific property name:

```cs
private static Type GetSpecificChildTypeOf(Type parent, string propertyName)
{
    var propType = typeof(ParentClass).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType;
    var elementType = propType.GetElementType();

    return elementType;
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
var childType = GetSpecificChildTypeOf(typeof(ParentClass), "Children");
Assert.True(childType == typeof(ChildClass))
```

Edit: Thanks for marking the answer!

Comment: This answer exhibits a more generic solution which I've been looking for.